# How to ignore lines that are between two patterns

Tags: bash, sed

I've used `sed` to print all lines starting from one pattern ending in another:

Lets say `file1` contents are these:

```
outside-text1
==START
inner-text1
==END
outside-text2
==START
inner-text2
==END
```

The command:

```
sed -n '/==START/,/==END/p' file1
```

will print :

```
==START
inner-text1
==END
==START
inner-text2
==END
```

In my case I would like to print:

```
outside-text1
outside-text2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove lines which are between given patterns from a file (using Unix tools)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996585/remove-lines-which-are-between-given-patterns-from-a-file-using-unix-tools)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negate the match with `!`.

```
$ sed -n '/==START/,/==END/!p' file1
outside-text1
outside-text2
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Or even easier, just use the `d` (delete) function to delete from the start to end patterns:

```
$ sed '/==START/,/==END/d' file.txt
outside-text1
outside-text2
```

It's just a cleaner alternative to suppressing printing of pattern-space and negating the print.

Comment: Gotcha -- you had me wondering what the heck was going on... `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, no offense sir but it was added in my 2nd solution too :)

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk '/^==END/{flag="";next} /^==START/{flag=1;next} !flag'   Input_file
```

OR

```
awk '/^==START/{flag=1;} /^==END/{flag="";next} !flag'  Input_file
```

OR

```
awk '/^==START/{flag=1} !flag;  /^==END/{flag=""}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
outside-text1
outside-text2
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Following `sed` may also help you in same.

```
sed  '/==START/,/==END/d'  Input_file
```

Comment: that can still be simplified ;)

Comment: @Sundeep, thanks, please see edited answer now and let me know if anything needed please.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15955111/3266847) has a nice way of doing it in awk.